# Moving to another country before my US visa interview?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I have a US B1/B2 visa interview in Country A, where I am a resident. However, I am moving to Country B before my visa interview date. I think it is not possible to move my interview to Country B. Although it would be difficult, I can come back to Country A for the visa interview. However, I may need to be a resident of Country A at the time of the interview, as that is normally the case.

Would the US change my interview date to an earlier date if I ask them? There are no free slots when I check.

Comment: What is your status (citizen? permanent resident? visa-holder? something else?) in both Country A and Country B?

Comment: Country A citizen/resident right now.
Country B will be a temp resident at the time of interview.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica some countries require visa applicants to reside in the consular district where they submit the application.  The Schengen visa code is particularly strict on this (and the implementing policies are even stricter, to the point of neglecting to consider exceptions that are explicit in the code or in the consular handbook).  User127373: the US has no such restriction except in specific circumstances (such as in consequence of certain past immigration violations).  Why do you think it's not possible to transfer your application to another consulate?

Comment: +90% of US embassies right now are only open to residents. If you know my situation is ok with them, how do I transfer it? Just email them?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica as far as I know, the requirements are imposed by the sending country, not the receiving country, so for a US visa application, the presence or absence of this requirement is determined by US law alone.  Country A and country B cannot impose rules that govern which individuals may apply for US visas at US consulate on their territory.

Comment: @phoog Yes, that's correct. I was confused. Thanks for the correction.  I will delete my comments.

Comment: @phoog I can transfer my app to another consulate, but not to another country